# iOS - NJSONSerialization causing a memory leak??(according to Instruments)

Tags: ios, memory-management, memory-leaks, nsjsonserialization, xcode-instruments

Below is the method with the code, where I am getting a memory leak using manual memory management. The memory leak is detected by using Xcode instruments and specifically points to the line where I am using NSJSONSerialization. I am running the target app (on a device with iOS 6.1).

The first time that i tap on the refreshButton there is no leak. Any subsequent tap generates the leak(and more leaks on top of that if i continue tapping the button). Below is the code - This is basic stuff for consuming JSON web services(the web service link is bogus but the real one that I am using works). You will notice that I am using Grand Central Dispatch so that I can update the UI without waiting for the parsing of the JSON to finish.

The line detected by instruments is surrounded by the asterisks. I would like to get some help to anyone who might have an idea of what is going on here. The full stack trace(as mentioned in the below comments i will put here:)

> +(NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:option:error:] -> -[_NSJSONReader parseData:options:] -> -[_NSJSONReader parseUTF8JSONData:skipBytes:options]->newJSONValue->newJSONString->[NSPlaceholde‌​rString
>   initWithBytes:length:encoding:]

```
-(void)parseDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictonary{

self.transactions = [dictonary objectForKey:@"transactions"];
if(!self.transactions){
    NSLog(@"Expected 'transactions' array");
    return;
}

for (int arrayIndex = 0; arrayIndex < [self.transactions count]; arrayIndex++) {
    TransactionResult *result = [[[TransactionResult alloc] init] autorelease];
    result.transactionID = [[self.transactions objectAtIndex:arrayIndex] objectForKey:@"ID"];
    result.transactionDescription = [[self.transactions objectAtIndex:arrayIndex] objectForKey:@"description"];
    result.transactionPrice = [[self.transactions objectAtIndex:arrayIndex] objectForKey:@"price"];
    self.totalPrice += [result.transactionPrice doubleValue];
    NSLog(@"total price: %f", self.totalPrice);
    [self.transactionResults addObject:result];
    result = nil;
}
```

}

```
 - (IBAction)refreshButtonPressed:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
        __block id resultObject;
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0),^{
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mywebservice.php"];
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

        NSError *error;
        ***resultObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];***

        if(!error){
            if([resultObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]){
                NSDictionary *dictonary = resultObject;
                [self parseDictionary:dictonary];
                NSLog(@"Done parsing!");
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    self.isLoading = NO;
                    [self.transactionsTableView reloadData];
                });
            }
            else{
                NSLog(@"JSON Error: Expected Dictionary");
                resultObject = nil;
                return;
            }
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"JSON Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                resultObject = nil;
                [self.transactionsTableView reloadData];
                [self showError];
            });
            return;
        }
    });
    }
```

Comment: My first question is always whether there's a reason you can't switch to ARC.

Comment: because unfortunately I am having to support iOS 4.3.

Comment: In that case, good news... iOS 4.3 supports ARCLite. ARCLite is ARC without zero-ing weak references. See [Objective-C Feature Availability Index](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ObjCAvailabilityIndex/index.html).

Comment: thats neat - thanks for the link. I would, however, like to figure out the problem at hand instead of trying to figure a way around it.

Comment: Fine, do it the hard way... :-) What does `parseDictionary` look like? Also, I don't think you need to call `release` on `resultObject` in the first `else` branch, since it should have been autoreleased. Are any of the `else` branches ever getting executed?

Comment: I have added the parseDictionary method. the inner else so far never gets executed because I am working with a web service that always returns dictionaries. However sometimes the web service doesnt respond which triggers an error and the outer else does get executed. I have added what I forgot before which is setting the resultObject to nil and assigning it as __block id resultObject at the beginning of the method as required.

Comment: The Instruments leak says that its a leaked object __NSCFString, responsible library, -[NSPlaceholderString initWithBytes:length:encoding:]. The full tree/stack trace is from the line in the code in question followed by +(NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:option:error:] -> -[_NSJSONReader parseData:options:] -> -[_NSJSONReader parseUTF8JSONData:skipBytes:options]->newJSONValue->newJSONString->[NSPlaceholderString initWithBytes:length:encoding:]. I dont see how any string here could have a leak and what string exactly?

Comment: Why do you care of it, does it cause crashes after while? Try using @autoreleasepool in dispatch_async. However, there still can be bug in Instruments.

Comment: Seems most likely that somewhere your code is retaining a string it shouldn't.  (BTW, have you run Analyzer?)

Comment: Analyzer doesn't pick up any errors/warnings at all when going to Run->Analyze ( i am using XCode 5). Like i said above, the stack trace where the supposed leak starts begins at the line in question and goes all the way down to the NSPLaceHolderString.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a ARC as soon as it came out with 4.3, and put an app in the store with it - point being you could switch to ARC. That said, I tried to reproduce your problem by creating a class/file that has the no-arc flag applied to it, but cannot reproduce the problem. This makes me believe your problem is elsewhere. In the code below, I create a Test object in another file, retain it, and send it the test message. No matter what I set "i" to, it always deallocs the object:

```
#import "Tester.h"

@interface Obj : NSObject <NSObject>
@end

@implementation Obj

- (id)retain
{
    NSLog(@"retain");
    id i = [super retain];
    return i;
}

- (oneway void)release
{
    NSLog(@"release");
    [super release];
}

- (void)foo
{

}

- (void)dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"Obj dealloced");
    [super dealloc];
}

@end

@implementation Tester

- (void)test
{
    int i = 2;

    __block Obj *obj;

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0),^{
        obj = [[Obj new] autorelease];

        if(i == 0) {
            Obj *o = obj;
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
                {
                    [o foo];
                } );
        } else if(i == 1) {
            obj = nil;
        } else if(i == 2) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
                {
                    obj = nil;
                } );
        }
    } );

}

@end
```

Comment: but you are not using NSJSONSerialization. I dont know but somehow i think that there is either a bug in the Instruments tool or there is something going on nasty with NSJSONSerialization. Please take a look at the call stack from Instruments and it shows you where the problem is. I am been going over my code and have yet to see where any of my NSStrings are leaking and Analyzer doesnt pick up any errors. Anything else that I might need to look for or is there anything within Instruments that would help me detect the problem further??

Comment: The point of the code was to test out the various ways blocks are retaining and releasing objects - and it works as I said in a non-ARC environment - the object is retained initially then released at the end, even if you nil out the variable in the middle of the block. You did not provide code for [self parseDictionary:dictonary], do you first release then retain the new dictionary? Also, your architecture is really not the best - you are using an Apple convenience routine to do a synchronous background fetch, on a concurrent queue, all to avoid using your own NSURLConnection + callbacks.